# How to set gluPerspective()'s zNear and zFar values for a given radius of a bounding sphere?

Tags: opengl

As many newbies to OpenGL and Graphics Programming, I'm having some problems to set the `zNear` and `zFar` values for `gluPerspective()`. Given that I know how big my scene is and taking into account the possible Depth Buffer problems I may have if I set the near plane too close. How can I set these parameters correctly?

In few words, if I know the radius of the scene's bounding sphere how can I set my projection the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe it is simple:

1. find centre (in Z axis) of the bounding sphere
2. near = centre.z - radius
3. far = centre.z + radius

Of course to find that centre you would have to iterate over whole visible objects or use some scene hierarchy.

Comment: Then what would it be the field of view angle?

Comment: since we are dealing with sphere then the field of view can be set to 90 degrees. Or you can use "atan2" function to calculate exact value for non spherical bounding boxes.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to worry much about losing depth buffer precision so long as you keep objects a reasonable distance from the camera.

The bits lost are the base two logarithm of the ratio `zFar/zNear`. In other words, for each bit of depth buffer precision you sacrifice, you can either double `zFar` or halve `zNear`. Logarithmic growth is something to be thankful for. Additionally, if you double *both* `zNear` and `zFar`, you sacrifice no additional bits of depth buffer precision.

`zNear=1` and `zFar=1024` costs you only 9 bits of depth buffer precision. That's a very comfortable space.

[See this FAQ for details](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/depthbuffer.htm):

> While the blue book description is good at pointing out the
>   relationship, it's somewhat inaccurate. As the ratio (zFar/zNear)
>   increases, less precision is available near the back of the depth
>   buffer and more precision is available close to the front of the depth
>   buffer. So primitives are more likely to interact in Z if they are
>   further from the viewer.

Field of view angle can be in the neighborhood of 90-70.